# permission denied while trying to install vue/cli

Tags: javascript, macos, vue.js

I'm trying to install vue cli in my project and I get that error, 
I'm a new MacOs user. 
hope you can help me fix it and install vue cli in my project.

```
Circus-MBP:TodoApp circus4$ npm i  @vue/cli -g

npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/vue'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/vue']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/vue'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!      path: '../lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js',
npm ERR!      dest: '/usr/local/bin/vue' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink \'../lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js\' -> \'/usr/local/bin/vue\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/vue' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Circus4/.npm/_logs/2019-10-07T12_38_25_842Z-debug.log
```

Comment: try to write `sudo npm i  @vue/cli -g`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need  to have permission  by writing `sudo` at the first of your command

```
sudo npm i  @vue/cli -g
```

### Updated

Or as **Philip** said it would be better than my answer

1. Create a directory in your home directory, say `~/.npm-global`.
2. run npm config set prefix `~/.npm-global`
3. Update your **PATH**: `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Please don't add other users' answers to yours to make it "updated". It's redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: i mention his name because his answer most valuable

Answer (score 48):

It seem's that you do not have the required privileges to install globally. You could either try installing with sudo or (recommended) move NPM's default directory to one which you have read/write permissions on:

1. Create directory in your home directory, say `~/.npm-global`.
2. run `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
3. Update your `PATH`: `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`

https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Notice that while you could probably just use sudo, this is highly discouraged. It even says so in the error output you posted:

> npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, **or try running**
>
> npm ERR! **the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended)**.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It works, it is safe, it is easy to do it. Whatever your reasons, executing npm as root is not a good idea.

Comment: sudo will cause everything to be created as root and owned by root causing more problem later on. this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have enough permissions. Try with `sudo`:

`sudo npm i -g @vue/cli`

Comment: Not sure this was marked down it was what worked for me by adding sudo at the beginning it then asked me for my password

Comment: Funny enough: I gave the first correct answer and got downvoted. But another one, who said the same thing gets upvoted and the checkmark.

Comment: @Dop4miN because sudo with npm is nothing you would want to call. Consider a second thought.

Answer (score 1):

Try it :

---

Log in as administrator

```
sudo su
```

And run

```
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the node version and update it to the latest version.
This worked for me.